# Group base looping in gsp

Tags: grails

I am having a list page its simple table where in I am rendering simple details like page title, summary, body, is-active etc., Here i want to display is-active pages list in a separate table and the pages which are not active in a separate table. Here i  want use single table to do this base on the is-active and in-active as group. Is there any way to do this in grails I am kinda new to grails just switch from ColdFusion to grails. Thanks

i wanted to do something like this.

```
<g:if test="${pageList.is-active}">
    list of active pages.
</g:if>
<g:else>
    list of Inactive pages
</g:else>
here table to be displayed with its respective page header. is there any group base looping in grails ?

               <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="1"></th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th class="center">Active</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <g:each in="${pageList}" status="i" var="map">
                            <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                                <td></td>
                                <td>${map.title}</td>
                                <td>${map.isActive}</td>
                            </tr>
                     </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to store the active and inactive pages separately in the model. Currently your controller action probably looks something like this:

```
def listPages() {
  [pageList: Page.list()]
}
```

If you change it so that the active and inactive pages are stored separately in the model

```
def listPages() {
  [active: Page.findAllByActive(true), inactive: Page.findAllByActive(false)]
}
```

Then you can easily render them separately in the view:

```
<h1>List of Active Pages</li>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="1"></th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th class="center">Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <g:each in="${active}" status="i" var="map">
      <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
        <td></td>
        <td>${map.title}</td>
        <td>${map.isActive}</td>
      </tr>
    </g:each>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1>List of Inactive Pages</li>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="1"></th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th class="center">Inactive</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <g:each in="${inactive}" status="i" var="map">
      <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
        <td></td>
        <td>${map.title}</td>
        <td>${map.isActive}</td>
      </tr>
    </g:each>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the interest of DRY, I would move the markup for rendering the `<table>` into a template, and pass it the list of pages in the model.

### Update

You indicated in a comment that you can't easily modify your query to separately return the active and inactive pages. In that case you can just filter them in the view like so:

```
<h1>List of Active Pages</li>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="1"></th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th class="center">Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <g:each in="${active}" status="i" var="map">
      <g:if test="${map.isActive}">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
          <td></td>
          <td>${map.title}</td>
          <td>${map.isActive}</td>
        </tr>
      </g:if>
    </g:each>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1>List of Inactive Pages</li>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="1"></th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th class="center">Inactive</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <g:each in="${inactive}" status="i" var="map">
      <g:if test="${!map.isActive}">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
          <td></td>
          <td>${map.title}</td>
          <td>${map.isActive}</td>
        </tr>
      </g:if>
    </g:each>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it seems like grails doesn't have group base looping. I am using HQL for listing and I am doing more in that query.

Comment: @webgeek I don't know what group base looping is, but I've proposed an alternative approach in my update